# Getting data from two mongodb collections (filtering on _id) in Meteor Application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-blaze

I am kind of having a problem over here for quite some time. I am creating a Meteor application where people can sign up for a group, upload some images and can give specific tags to their images. I got a specific collection for Tags that hold an *_id* and a *name* element.

The tags that a user can use, for their images, are stored in a Group collection, but this collection got an array (with the available tags *_ids* stored in that field)

**Groups Collection - Single Entry**

```
{ 
"_id" : "uC3PRu3qdcAF2tKK8", 
"name" : "Summer Festival 2017", 
"token" : "SummerFunUnited", 
"tags" : [ "c6vMNnfJzFjEqDSJv", "RYNSsvmafCdRZ6Me9", "9qJD5L6PYCEcbEKcb" ]
 }
```

The Tags stored in Tags collection are stored like:

**Mongo Tags Collection**

```
{ "_id" : "c6vMNnfJzFjEqDSJv", "name" : "Summerfanatic" }
{ "_id" : "RYNSsvmafCdRZ6Me9", "name" : "Sunshineaddict" }
{ "_id" : "9qJD5L6PYCEcbEKcb", "name" : "Danceman" }
```

I want to create an Admin Panel where an administrator can lookup what tags are being used in an specific group. The route is working fine, and I can get the name of the group in my Meteor template.

The problem is, if I want to show the **names** of the tags per Group I can't get it to work. My Mongo Queries are not working, or I really am doing something wrong.

If I use and Query like:

```
Groups.find({ tags: { $in: [ "c6vMNnfJzFjEqDSJv", "RYNSsvmafCdRZ6Me9", "9qJD5L6PYCEcbEKcb" ] }})
```

I get no results back.

I really hope you guys can help me out, or know an alternative for storing tags in a more proper way (in the Future there must still be added new tags by the administrators).

Kind Regards!

Comment: I see no special issue in your data structure. But why are you querying `Groups` if your objective is to lookup _tags_? And why the double curly braces in the selector?

Comment: The double curly braces are because of overwriting it in stack-overflow (sorry for the typo, it is not in my code). 

The problem is I don't know where to start with the Mongo queries, so not really have an awnser why I am looking in my Groups collection. 

In a short anwser: I don't know what to do to make it work.

Comment: Your use of [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) looks correct and your model structure makes sense as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query means:

"*find Group document which `tags` field contains at least one value (i.e. Tag id) in the given array*".

So that would be relevant for listing Groups associated with some given Tags.

You say you want to list Tags (by name) associated with a given Group.

This sounds like a pretty straight forward query, once you have the desired Group document data in hand:

"*find Tag documents which `_id` field is within the given array*"

Then use your Blaze template to loop through those Tags and display their `name`.

Something like:

**Spacebars**

```spacepars
{{#each groupDoc in groupDocs}}
    {{> groupTemplate groupDoc1=groupDoc}}
{{/each}}

<template name="groupTemplate">
    {{#each tagDoc in tagsDocs groupDoc1}}
        {{tagDoc.name}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
Template.groupTemplate.helpers({
    tagsDocs: function (groupDoc) {
        var tagsIdArray = groupDoc.tags;

        return Tags.find({
            _id: {
                $in: tagsIdArray
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Using the Tags.find() query with $in of group.tags array has solved my problem! .. Thank you very much.. I still need a lot to learn i guess!